# In python how can i add a gedit plugin for compiling a c program?

Tags: python, plugins, gedit

I am trying to create a plugin in gedit for compiling  c program. For this, i need to add a button also. when i am pressing this  button it should compile the currently opened c program. And also dislay a message in terminal.I am new to python, so please help me with the code...

Comment: First of all i suggest looking at [Gedit Python plugins howto](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo), then you can investigate [various](https://github.com/phsilva/gedit-pylint) [plugins](https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu) created by other gedit users .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i could compile a particular c file ( hello.c) using this :
`p=subprocess.Popen("gcc -o hello hello.c",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
             (output, err)=p.communicate()`
the thing is that,i need to compile 'any' c file by fetching the file name and substituting there in this code. I tried alot.bt i failed. please help me